# Does your Microsoft Publisher ID have to be kept private?

Tags: windows-store-apps, publishing

From the Microsoft Dev Center, your [**`Publisher ID`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967786.aspx#display_info) is...

> the string that uniquely identifies your Windows Store developer account in your packages. The publisher ID is assigned by Microsoft, and you can't change it.

This is likely to appear in a lot of Open Source repositories for Windows 8 because it is listed in the [`identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211441.aspx) element of the `Package.appxmanifest` file which is required in order to build your project.

A search of [extension:appxmanifest](https://github.com/search?q=extension%3Aappxmanifest&type=Code&ref=searchresults) on GitHub reveals almost 5,000 files with this info since the appxmanifest is not on the default gitignore.

Here's GitHub's Help Page on [Removing Sensitive Data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data), but I'm wondering if there's a reason to be worried about it in the first place.

*Q: Is there a security reason why this should remain private?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q: Is there a security reason why this should remain private?**

I will not say that this is because of the 100% security reason. But there are other factors as well. As this **Publisher ID** which you have obtained from your developer account at the Store will help you create a certificate with a Publisher ID of your choice. You can also create a password.

Publisher ID helps you in signing an app package

> If you either create a package for the Windows Store or associate your
>   app with it, the Publisher attribute is set to the Publisher ID that’s
>   obtained from your developer account at the Store when you sign in
>   during package creation.

So it is your publisher ID which is actually identifying you. So its better to keep it secure.(*It is very similar to take it like you will not like to give your bank account details to anyone except the bank ;-)*)

So if your publisher ID is not secure or is public then you may loose that choice.

Check this [To create or use an alternate certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230260%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Your answer isn't quite clear to me. Could you clarify? It sounds like you're saying, "No, you don't have to keep it private for security reasons, but it is personal information that you might not want to share widely, just like you may not want someone else to know your username even if they don't know your password."

Answer (score 5):

There is almost no reason under normal circumstances to keep your Microsoft Publisher ID private. (I wouldn't be surprised if there's some unique edge case where you would want to keep it private. Somebody else would have to help me out there.)

Your publisher ID is distributed every time somebody downloads your app from the Windows Store. You can view this for any app by manually opening its AppxManifest.xml, or you can use PowerShell: `(Get-AppxPackage -Name "*_APPNAME_*" | Get-AppxPackageManifest).Package.Identity.Publisher`

For example, `(Get-AppxPackage -Name "*netflix*" | Get-AppxPackageManifest).Package.Identity.Publisher` returns
`CN=52120C15-ACFA-47FC-A7E3-4974DBA79445`, and running the command on an app I've published to the Windows Store gives me my personal Publisher ID.

Answer (score 1):

Kunal Chowdhury, a Microsoft MVP, has his on a blog post. I suspect that if an MVP is comfortable doing so, then it is probably safe.

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/12/what-is-packageappxmanifest-file-in.html

Mabye consider contacting and asking Mr. Chowdhury. I'm sure he could give you good advice in this area.

Comment: I appreciate the link, but there are thousands of Microsoft MVP's and I wouldn't always consider them experts on every subject just in virtue of the fact that they passed a couple programming tests.  He could also be using a self-signed certificate with no real world implications.